# postman could not sen request if i insert const { collection } = require

Tags: node.js, mongoose, collections, postman, backend

as soon as I insert const { collection } = require('../../public/src/js/db');
my backend no longer connects and I get the message from the postman:Could not send request
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000

post.routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { collection } = require('../../public/src/js/db');

// eine GET-Anfrage
router.get('/', async(req, res) => {

    res.send({ message: "Hello 27773!" });
});

// GET all posts
router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    const allPosts = await collection.find().toArray();
    res.status(200);
    res.send(allPosts);
});
```

// POST one new post
router.post('/', async(req, res) => {

```
try {
    const newPost = {
        title: req.body.title,
        location: req.body.location,
        image_id: req.body.image_id,
        txt: req.body.txt
    }
    const result = await collection.insertOne(newPost);
    res.status(201);
    res.send(result);
} catch {
    res.status(404);
    res.send({
        error: "Post does not exist!"
    });
}
```

});

module.exports = router;
`

And my db.js looks like:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
require('dotenv').config();

const client = new MongoClient(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, {
  
  });


const dbconnection = client.connect();
const database = client.db(process.env.DB_NAME);
const collection = database.collection(process.env.COLLECTION);
console.log(`Connected to DB ... `);

module.exports.client = client;
module.exports.dbconnection = dbconnection;
module.exports.database = database;
module.exports.collection = collection;
```